# I need to test USB performance with Ext2 and Ext3 filesystems

Tags: usb, filesystems, performance-monitor, speedtest

Any tool which gives exact speed and cpu usage information?

Likely dd and hdparm tools.

Ouput is likely to come as below links:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI81XX_PSP_04.04.00.01_Feature_Performance_Guide#SATA_-_ext2_File_System_Performance

Thanks in Advance.
Ravi Bhuva

Comment: EXT2 better see http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_310_10fs&num=3 , but need test for your typical task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bonnie++: http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/
It's packaged in most linux distros